# sharethis on twitter bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, sharethis

I wanted to show the share-this widget on a twitter bootstrap modal, however the code says to do the following:

```
<span class='st_facebook_hcount' displayText='Facebook'></span>
<span  class='st_twitter_hcount' displayText='Tweet'></span>
<span class='st_plusone_hcount' displayText='Google +1'></span>
<span  class='st_email_hcount' displayText='Email'></span>
```

so what I did is that on bootstrap's shown.bs.modal event I have:

```
var switchTo5x=true;
    $.getScript("http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js", function(){
        stLight.options({publisher: "c68c8f6c-c670-419b-b8e2-23772e22a861", doNotHash: false, doNotCopy: false, hashAddressBar: false, popup: 'true'});

    });
```

however the next time I open a different modal, then this share button doesn't load. I assume it's because the getScript is already there?

Comment: Appreciate this is an old answer, but I'll just leave this here. The docs say to use `window.__sharethis__.initialize()` when the modal is visible: https://sharethis.com/support/guides/reinitialize-sharethis-buttons-specific-sharing-parameters/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this after opening new modals:

```
stButtons.locateElements();
```

It will look for the new buttons and it will instantiate them.

Edit: [Listen to the `show.bs.modal` event to handle it](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) :

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
  stButtons.locateElements();
})
```

Edit2:
Ok after reading your comment I think that the final solution is:

```
var switchTo5x=true;
    $.getScript("http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js", function(){
        stLight.options({publisher: "c68c8f6c-c670-419b-b8e2-23772e22a861", doNotHash: false, doNotCopy: false, hashAddressBar: false, popup: 'true'});
        stButtons.locateElements();
    });
```

Comment: that does nothing actually, if I put it inside my getScript, it works =). But I get the point, I'll accept the answer

Comment: I had the same issue with unresponsive ShareThis buttons.  I was updating a page's content with AJAX and the PURE JS templating tool. Not loading the ShareThis scripts on page load and instead loading them with your getScript idea worked perfectly.